# Sharepoint 2010 How to change language at runtime 

Tags: 2010

I have tryied for some days now to figure out how to make it possible in SP 2010 to change the title on site columns and lists etc. at runtime according to the choosen language.

I have installed several language packages, and are able to change the language on the build in menues, navigation ...

I have define some ressource files Language.da-DK.resx and Language.en-UK.resx and deployied those to 
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Resources on the server. 
and also tryied 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\App_GlobalResources without any luck!

In my filed definitions I refere the ressource files as follows:

```
<FieldRef DisplayName="$Resources:Language, Name"/>
```

When i make a new site sollection and choose danish as the default language, the strings defined in Language.da-DK.resx is used when I define new lists etc. But when i change the language to english at runtime the strings from Language.en-UK.resx are not loaded.

If i manually change the titles via the webinterface SP renembers my translantions!

Is there any way that i can configure SP to load the strings dynamically from Language.en-UK.resx

---

Sorry to say, it did not work. My field titles om my custom list are not translated when i change language from DK to EN.

I think it is possible, because when you build your list with the default columns in Sharepoint these are translated when you change language. Department get translated to Afdeling when i change from English to Danish. I i have not touch a thing to get this work !!

Answer (score 2):

Erm, this might be too obvious, but isn't the code for 'UK English' "en-gb"? Have you tried naming your language file "Language.en-GB.resx"?

Answer (score 1):

The resource file is just used during field/list creation. You can use the TitleResource property on the SPField object to programmatically set the value for each language post creation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to add the resx files in the inetpub/wwwroot/VirtualDirectories/port/App_GlobalResources